# Change notchedOutline span text color in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently trying to customise the textfield of materialUI. [Here is what I am trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4aBD.png)

I am having difficulty trying to access and change the color of the `span` tag that the text resides in. At the same time, i am also having difficulty in persisting the border color when the `textfield` is in focus. I do not quite understand how these (peusdo selectors?) work. How & when do i nest them or use them, for that matter.

e.g.

```
"& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
        "& fieldset": {
          borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)"  // default
        },
        "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
          border: "2px solid red"             // focus
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what component are you using? `TextField`?

Comment: @Rajiv yep that is right, using a textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for styling the label of `TextField`, use the `InputLabelProps` and target the focused class of the label.

```
<TextField
    InputLabelProps={{ classes: { focused: classes.labelRoot } }}
    variant="outlined"
    label="Colored Label"
/>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    labelRoot: {
        "&&": {
            color: "pink"
        }
    }
}));
```

In `labelRoot` class, `"&&"` is used for increasing the specificity to override the default style.

Here is the working demo:

[image: Edit clever-haibt-3z3y9]

For styling it in theme:-

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiFormLabel:{
            root:{
                '&$focused':{
                    color:'green'
                }
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way to do set this in material UI theme? I tried doing the same under overrides but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: for doing it in theme, target the `MuiFormLabel` in overrides and use the `focused` rule. I've updated the codesandbox.. have a look

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks so much! what is the $ in front of focused for? how does it compare to `&:focused`

Comment: `&:focused` is used for targeting the element on focused state, whereas the `$` is used for targeting the ruleName. [Read More](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet). This link might help to understand more

Comment: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.5.1#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet here aslo explained about the `$` selector